# jQuery call function if object with specific class clicked?

Tags: jquery, class

I have an unordered list with some links. Some links have a class "A" others have a class "B".
I'd like to call a jQuery function depending on which class is clicked, but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('.yourClass').click(function(e){
    //do something here
});
```

Comment: Example: `<li><b><a href="#" class="Page">test</a></b></li>` then using 
`$(document).ready(function(){
$('.Page').click(function(e){
alert('Clicked');
});

});` doesn't do anything, no errors if firebug but no alert.

Comment: take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/BdwTJ/ . The example you provided works. Maybe this is not your problem. Did you load query correctly?

Comment: jQuery is loaded correctly, it's being used for other things on the page without any problems. I made a new test. The list was being generated by the jquery tmpl plugin. If I create a list with identical properties by hand on the same page the click function works fine. I guess this is down to the rendering not working with my tmpl generated list.

Comment: try defining the click event after your list has been loaded

Comment: I've tried this also by having the click event at the in script tags below everything else, but before the closing html tag. Here is a proof of concept example of the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962556/jquery-tmpl-plugin-problems-with-template-results-from-dynamic-content-bug

Comment: I've accepted this answer, as it does work, just not when used with jQuery templates. I think this is a different issue. Thanks

Comment: I answered your other question where you put some code on jsfiddle!

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you simply check the class inside the function ?

```
$("ol li a").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("A")) {
        // Do stuff if class = "A"
    } else if ($(this).hasClass("B")) {
        // Do stuff if class = "B"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".A").click(function() {
  // do stuff for A
});

$(".B").click(function() {
  // do some other different stuff for B
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('.A').click(function() { handler here })
jQuery('.B').click(function() { another handler here })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("LI.A").click(function() {  
    //your stuff  
});
```